# Como ingresar una cantidad indefinida de valores en un array(vector) y finalizar la carga con una letra, ejemplo 'F'

Tags: c++

quiero hacer un programa que pueda ingresar una cantida de valores indefinido en un vector, y que salga del ciclo y deje de ingresar valores cuando ingrese una letra por ejemplo 'F' de finalizar. Este es el codigo que masomenos imagino, pero ya intente de otras formas pero no logro que funcione.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> v1;
void data();

int main()
{
    int J;
    datos();
    J=v1.size();
    for(int i=0;i<J;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d",v1[i]);
    }
    system("pause");
}

void data()
{
    int X;
    char a='f';
    printf("Enter the values of the vector below, enter the letter 'f' to finish loading\n");
    scanf("%d",&X);
    while(X!=a)
    {
        v1.push_back(X);
        scanf("%d",&X);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas comparando un entero con un caracter, tu programa espera el código ascii de la letra 'f' por lo tanto tu programa espera el número 102 y no la letra 'f' para terminar.

Esta sería una implementación alternativa de lo que buscas:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> v;
    string in;
    while (cin >> in, in != "f") {
        try {
            v.push_back(stoi(in));
        } catch (exception &e) {
            cout << in << " no se puede convertir a entero" << endl;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int) v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando, y se adapta a lo que necesito hacer a continuación

Answer (score 1):

Cosas raras que tienes por ahí:

```
std::vector< int > v1;
...
int J;
...
J = v1.size( );
```

Ya empezamos mal. La función-miembro `size( )` devuelve un valor del tipo `vector< int >::size_type`.

```
...
datos( );
...
```

Esa función **no existe** en tu código. Si existe `data( )`.

```
...
int X;
char a = 'f';
scanf( "%d", &X );

while( X != a ) {
...
```

Ese bloque de código **no hace** lo que esperas. `scanf( )` **no funciona así**. Tal y como lo tienes, tu bucle terminará solo cuando el usuario introduzca el valor `102` (código ASCII del carácter `f`).

Podrías usar la I/O propia de C++, pero, en tu caso particular, es más simple utilizar `scanf( )` como lo estás haciendo, aunque usándolo correctamente. `scanf( )` devolverá `0` **cuando no pueda leer ningún valor**, y esa es la característica que puedes utilizar.

Tu código, corregido (limitado a C++98):

```
vector< int > v1;
void data( );

int main( ) {
  data( );

  std::vector< int >::size_type J = v1.size( );
  for( int i = 0; i < J; ++i ) {
    printf( "\n%d", v1[i] );
  }

  system( "pause" );

  return 0;
}

void data( ) {
  int X;
  printf( "Enter the values of the vector below, enter the letter 'f' to finish loading\n" );

  while( scanf( "%d", &X ) ) {
    v1.push_back( X );
  }
}
```

Ese código terminará **en cuanto el usuario introduzca algo que no es un número**. No es necesario que sea exactamente el caracter `f`.

Aun podríamos hacer algunos cambios ahí: no son necesarias las variables globales, estas se pueden pasar como argumentos a la función, recorrer el vector usando iteradores, ...

Comment: Gracias por ser tan detallado en mis errores, me ayudó de mucho